# Axios loop & concatenate

Tags: javascript, loops, axios

I have an axios all/spread calling multiple .json files and I'm concatenating the responses to get a merged array of the responses.

```
axios.all([
    axios.get("json/data1.json",config),
    axios.get("json/data2.json",config),
    axios.get("json/data3.json",config)
])
.then(axios.spread(function (data1, data2, data3) {
    var data1 = response1.data || [];
    var data2 = response2.data || [];
    var data3 = response3.data || [];
    var merged = data1.concat(data2.concat(data3.concat));
}))
```

Now for simplicity purposes, I want to automate all of that, as the number of .json files I get are much more than 3, and I would like to use a loop for the data[x] json files and to automate the concatenation..

I'm not sure about what would be the best approach to do that?

Comment: `axios.get` returns a promise, so simply pass an array of those promises to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and it will give you back an array of resolved values.

Answer (score 0):

How about mapping them like below:

```
Promise.all([
  axios.get("json/data1.json", config),
  axios.get("json/data2.json", config),
  axios.get("json/data3.json", config)
]).then(responses => responses.map(resp => resp.data || []));
```

Comment: So i guess this is how I should do it for the response part as opposed to the concatenation I was doing before. But then what about the axios.get loop from let's say a list of available values? How do I do that?

Comment: What loop are you talking about?

Comment: I don't know how to loop through a list, like var = [data1, data2, data3] and then do an axios.get on each element of this list.

Comment: This is what I tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/5km5lv5o7n

The issue is that I want to concatenate the .data and not the object. I currently get this:  

[Object, Object, Object] ▶0: Object ▶data: Object userId: 1 id: 1 title: "delectus aut autem" completed: false status: 200 statusText: "" ▶headers: Object ▶config: Object ▶request: XMLHttpRequest.  

 And what I would like is:   

[Object, Object, Object] ▶0: Object userId: 1 id: 1 title: "delectus aut autem" completed: false status: 200 statusText: ""

Comment: Hey Thanks it seems to be better now indeed.. The last issue I have is that now I get a flow of Array / Array / Obj, while before I had Array / Obj. Not sure Why the mapping added an array..

Comment: So I'm not sure how to explain that but I'll try my best..

Basically What I get with this is: Array -> Array -> Obj, but what I want is this Array -> Obj

Not sure why, but before, when I had the individuals get. and the .concat it was like this. But now that I'm using the .map it added an array inbetween>

Comment: @Vincent Ask a new question, or if you feel it is really hard to write as a question, then you make try this https://www.codementor.io service to unstuck you. I am also there, you can get the link of my profile from my stackoverflow profile.. Do what feels more appropriate.